# How to solve $4$th degree polynomial if only $3$ points are known

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

I'm currently revising my notes for upcoming exam in derivative calculus and I have stumbled upon one question I can not solve. Maybe someone can guide me/help me to understand how to solve this:

It is known that the fourth degree polynomial $P(x)$ is greater than or equal to $x$ for all real $x$. It is also known that $P(1)=1$, $P(2)=4$, and $P(3)=3$. Determine the value of $P(4)$.

I have gotten this:
Fourth degree polynomial formula:
$P(x)\ge x,\quad P(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$

- $P(1)= a(1)^4+b(1)^3+c(1)^2+d(1)+e =1 \iff 1a+1b+1c+1d+e=1$
- $P(2)= a(2)^4+b(2)^3+c(2)^2+d(2)+e =4 \iff 16a+8b+4c+2d+e=4$
- $P(3) = a(3)^4+b(3)^3+c(3)^2+d(3)+e=3 \iff 81a+27b+9c+3d+e=3$

And here I'm stuck because I need two more equations to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to format your posts. Additionally, this website can be more helpful to you if you provide details such as what you've tried so far.

Comment: Maybe you could consider $f(x) = P(x)-x$?

Comment: As a followup to Student's comment, can you factor $P(x)-x$, at least partially?

Comment: What you already have is $$\pmatrix{ c = -25 a-6 b-2 \\ d = 60 a + 11 b + 9 \\ e = -6 ( 6 a+b+1) } $$

Comment: A clue is that the function must remain above the $y=x$ line when $x=1, 3$ . this puts constraints on the derivatives and thus provides the other two equations.

Comment: Using Student's suggestion, you have three important pieces of information: $f(1)=0$, $f(3)=0$, and $f(x)\geq 0$. Therefore, $1$ and $3$ are double roots of $f$.

Comment: Maybe this [visual clue](https://i.imgur.com/iI3GpuK.png) should help you understand what is going on at the roots of $P(x)-x$.

Comment: @Student I think you could flesh that out to an answer! Your call, of course :-)

Comment: Student plus @Gonçalo leaves only one degree of freedom remaining.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen seems like i'm a little late to the party, haha!

Comment: Afraid, so @Student :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the comment of Student: Let $Q(x):=P(x)-x$. This function satisfies $Q(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. It also has two roots: $x_1=1$ and $x_2=3$. These roots can't be first degree roots, since then the graph would cross the $x$-axis, violating the condition that $Q$ is non-negative. But if they are both at least second degree roots, then they must be the only roots (and be exactly of degree two), since a fourth degree polynomial can't have more than four roots, counted by multiplicity. So we must have

$$Q(x)=a(x-1)^2(x-3)^2.$$

Given that $Q(2)=2$, we get $a\cdot 1^2\cdot(-1)^2=2$, that is, $a=2$. So

$$Q(x)=2(x-1)^2(x-3)^2.$$

The rest is just trivial calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Given the three points you have

$$P(x) = \tfrac{-6 d-11 e-12}{36} x^4 + \tfrac{3 d+5 e+3}{3} x^3 + \tfrac{-66 d-85 e+12}{36} x^2 + d x + e $$

and since the curve must be above or at $y=x$ at the nodes of $P(1)=1$ and $P(3)=3$ you have the additional conditions of

$$ \left. \lim_{x=1} \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x} P(x) = 1 \right\}\;\; \frac{-6 d-17 e+42}{18}=1 $$

and

$$\left. \lim_{x=3} \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x} P(x) = 1 \right\} \;\; \frac{-6 d-13 e-42}{6}=1 $$

which you can solve for $d$ and $e$.

Comment: This works (+1), but taking Student's comment fully into account there is only a single unknown variable left to be determined.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, no because $d \neq 1$ so $P(x)-x$ still has a coefficient with an $x$ term.

Comment: I meant that according to the comment the polynomial must have the form
$$P(x)-x=A(x-1)^2(x-3)^2,$$ and the remaining task is to determine the value of $A$. That's exactly how Vercassivelaunos also decided to do it. Your approach is fine, too, which is why I upvoted.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - Oh, I see now. Yes, that would be a better approach. At least it avoids solving systems of equations.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach,

Using the same $Q(x) = P(x) - x \ge 0$, since $Q(1) = 0$ and $Q(3) = 0$, that implies $Q'(1) = 0$ and $Q'(3) = 0$, which leaves you with $5$ equation and $5$ variables.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your shoes, I would write your equation in the most general way:

$$P(x) = a (x - b) (x-1) (x-2) (x-3) + S(x)$$

... where $S(x)$ is a second degree equation, for which $S(1)=1$, $S(2)=4$ and $S(3)=3$. (You can find this, using the method you described in your question, the solution is $S(x) = -2x^2+9x-6$)

For which values of $a$ and $b$ is $P(x)>x$ ($\forall x$)?
=> Filling in those values and calculating $P(4)$ should solve your problem.